# Pull a row of data from multiple tabs in Google Sheets and display in one Master Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to create a master sheet within a Google Sheets document which pulls a row of data (C33:AC33) from each tab (while excluding the following tabs: Menu, Template, Class List). I need to use a script because the tabs will constantly change and be added to.

I need the new data to be displayed from the 5th row, 2nd column on the master sheet. In the 1st column, I wanted to display the name of the tab the data came from.

Is this possible? I've been looking for hours and this is the closest snippet of code I've found which I think could possibly do what I need however I am a script newbie and don't know if I'm on the right track:

```
function pullRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const arr = ss
    .getSheets()
    .filter(s => !s.getName().includes('Master', 'Template', 'Class List';))
    .flatMap(s => s.getDataRange(C33:AC33).getValues());
flatten it
  ss.getSheetByName('Master')
    .getRange(5, 2, arr.length, arr[0].length)
    .setValues(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of the cells "C33:AC33" from sheets except for `'Master', 'Template', 'Class List'`.
- You want to put the values to 'Master` sheet. In this case, you want to put each value from each sheet for each row by adding the sheet name to the top column.
- You want to put those values from the cell "B5".

#### Modification points:

- About `!s.getName().includes('Master', 'Template', 'Class List';)`, when you want to use this, please modify it to `!['Master', 'Template', 'Class List'].includes(s.getSheetName()`.
- About `s.getDataRange(C33:AC33).getValues()`, `getDataRange` has not arguments. And `C33:AC33` is not string value.
- In this case, I would like to propose the following flow.

  1. Retrieve the values from each sheet except for 'Master', 'Template', 'Class List'.
  2. Put the final values to Master sheet.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function pullRows() {
  // 1. Retrieve the values from each sheet except for 'Master', 'Template', 'Class List'.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const arr = ss
    .getSheets()
    .filter(s => !['Master', 'Template', 'Class List'].includes(s.getSheetName()))
    .map(s => [s.getSheetName(), ...s.getRange("C33:AC33").getValues()[0]]);

  // 2. Put the final values to Master sheet.
  ss.getSheetByName('Master')
    .getRange(5, 2, arr.length, arr[0].length)
    .setValues(arr);
}
```

#### Note:

- When you want to put each value from each sheet for each column by adding the sheet name to the top row, you can also use the following script. I couldn't understand which you want to achieve. So as the additional script, I added the following script.

  ```
    function pullRows() {
      // 1. Retrieve the values from each sheet except for 'Master', 'Template', 'Class List'.
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      const arr = ss
        .getSheets()
        .filter(s => !['Master', 'Template', 'Class List'].includes(s.getSheetName()))
        .map(s => [s.getSheetName(), ...s.getRange("C33:AC33").getValues()[0]]);

      // 2. Transpose the retrieved values.
      const res = arr[0].map((_, i) => arr.map(r => r[i]));

      // 3. Put the final values to Master sheet.
      ss.getSheetByName('Master')
        .getRange(5, 2, res.length, res[0].length)
        .setValues(res);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you Tanaike! This is perfect and exactly what I want to do - except that instead of the results displaying vertically in columns, is there a way I can show it in rows? Example: Sheet 1 - B5, Sheet 2 - B6 etc..

Comment: @BLibrary If you try the first code snippet, you'll notice the data is getting displayed in rows, as you wanted. I'm not sure whether you want the sheet names to be displayed in column A instead, in which case you should make a small modification when specifying the destination range (`.getRange(5, 1, res.length, res[0].length)`).

Comment: Thanks lamblichus - I would like the names in Column A so have made that tweak but my results are still showing in columns for some reason?

Comment: @B Library Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my answer, the 2nd sample script puts vertically the values. But, the 1st sample script is for achieving your replying. The values are put horizontally. Can you confirm it? If that was also not the direction you expect, can I ask you about the detail output you expect?

Comment: @Iamblichus Thank you for your always support. From OP's question, I had thought that the values are put from the column "B".

Comment: @B Library If you want to put the sheet name and values of "C33:AC33" to the column "A" and the columns after the column "B", I think that you can achieve that with `.getRange(5, 1, res.length, res[0].length)` for the 1st script as Iamblichus's comment.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike - I would like the results horizontally in rows - the script you gave me is perfect, but just horizontally instead :)

Comment: @B Library Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about your goal. So can you provide the sample output you expect? From this, I would like to modify the script.

Comment: I am currently using the second script you originally gave me which is perfect - I'd just like it to display that exact output in horizontal rows, rather than columns (I hope that makes sense)

Comment: @B Library Thank you for replying. I could understand that you are using 2nd sample script. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about `I'd just like it to display that exact output in horizontal rows, rather than columns (I hope that makes sense)`. So can you provide the sample output you expect? From this, I would like to modify the script.

Comment: Apologies Tanaike - it is not your English skills but my novice scripting skills! I just tried the first script you provided and it works absolutely perfectly! Thank you so much for all of your help!!

Comment: @B Library Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the 1st script, when you want to change the start column, please modify it like `.getRange(5, 1, res.length, res[0].length)` as Iamblichus's 1st comment.